# PHP on Windows using system function - Why errors not in the correct place

Tags: php, mysql, windows

I am using the PHP system function on windows as follows:

```
system("mysql --user=root --password=xxxx --host=127.0.0.1 --verbose <create.sql > out.txt 2>&1", $retVal);
```

But the error messages apppear at the top of the file. Is it possible to get the error messages to appear after the appropriate line of SQL that has the error.

Comment: what do you mean by: But the error messages apppear at the top of the file?

Comment: All the output (as you can see) both STDERR and STDOUT goes to the file out.txt. The STDERR stuff is at the top and STDOUT is at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that stdout is buffered and stderr is not meaning that the errors will always show first in this case.  You are going to need to wrap your system call in a script and sort it afterwards if you wish to retain some sort of order.  There is some explanation available [over here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/126488-preserve-output-order-when-redirecting-stdout-stderr.html).